# Kerning with `realscripts` and LuaLaTex

Tags: footnotes, kerning

If I use lining superscript numbers for footnotes with `realscripts` package, I realize that it uses locally `\addfontfeature`, so there is no kerning. Please, consider this trivial case:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\babelfont[english]{rm}[Ligatures=TeX,Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle}]{Source Serif Pro}
\usepackage{realscripts}
\begin{document}
To be, or not to be\footnote{xxx}.
\end{document}
```

I adjusted some kerning into the font to eliminate excessive space between the superscript number and following period (or comma), but it does't work for the aforementioned reasons.

Referring to this thread:
[Lining numbers for footnote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473983/lining-numbers-for-footnote) I ask:

1. is the only method to have real lining superscript to resort to `realscripts`?

Referring to this thread:
[Adjusting kerning with LuaTeX and realscripts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/362649/adjusting-kerning-with-luatex-and-realscripts)

2. if it's so, is there a way to "automatize" the procedure for footnote numbers?

Comment: There’s `fnpct`, but it’s broken at the moment. The problem [has been reported](https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/fnpct/issues/17/fncpt-unworkable-with-new-version-of-latex).

Comment: thank you. I see it applies kerning with LaTeX settings. Is it able simply to apply the kerning built into the font?

Comment: And is it compatible with alla classical classes as article and book, or only KOMA-Script?

Comment: You haven’t explained how you want the output to look, so I can’t say whether `fnpct` will satisfy you once it’s no longer in a broken state. But its manual describes very many options.